# Make "Broadcast from <name>" optional?

Tags: actions-on-google

Since 2 days, my google home, which is integrated with my smart home system, started saying "Broadcast from " followed by the actual Smart Home announcement, e.g. the washing machine is ready etc.

Since there is also an integration with Nest Hello (which plays a doorbell sound, followed by a spoken text) i know it is possible to skip the "Announcement from " part. Anybody care to share tips/workarounds?

Using: https://github.com/greghesp/assistant-relay

Comment: How are you doing it right now? Nest Hello is using a separate, partner-specific API for smart home devices, but it looks like you're directly sending Broadcast commands to your Google Home.

Comment: That is correct @NickFelker i was hoping Google would open that one up also.. Would the communication from Nest doorbell to Google Home happen via cloud or locally via bell -> home? If it would be local then i would be able to sniff it.

Comment: It works through the cloud